# vue.js Uncaught TypeError: this.$emit is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

```
export default {    
    mounted() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        this.$emit('onLoad')
      }, 4000);
    }
} //views/Load.vue
```

I want to move to another page when 4seconds after page access.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
      <router-view
        @onLoad="changeRoute('login')">
      </router-view>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  methods: {
    changeRoute (routeName) {
      this.$router.push({ name: routeName })
    }
  }
}
</script> //App.vue
```

I want to send a signal to 'App.vue' by '$emit' and then go to the page that is connected by router.

All routers are connected properly.

but the error of "Uncaught TypeError: this.$emit is not a function" apperas.

How can I do?

Comment: Use an arrow function for your `setTimeout` callback to preserve the surrounding `this` value.

Comment: Thank you!! The error has been resolved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue could be the function inside the `setTimeout` not being binded to the context , so you can try using an arrow function or [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the function the the outer context:

```js
export default {    
    mounted() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.$emit('onLoad')
      }, 4000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using an arrow function solved the problem. thank you!